# Pasar como parámetro todas las columnas de una Matriz a la funcion selm en R

Tags: r

Tengo una matriz de datos `mydata` de 10 variables x `n` observaciones y la quiero pasar como parámetro a la función `selm`. Lo vengo haciendo de esta forma:

```
m3=selm(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10)~1,family="SN",data=mydata,method="MLE")
```

pero como planeo utilizar matrices con diferentes cantidades de variables estoy buscando una forma de generalizar el script. El tema es que no puedo hacer el `cbind` de todas las variables (`cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10)`) sin tener que enumerarlas a mano.

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?  Probé con paste pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo. La utilización de `paste` es justamente la solución. ¿Qué debelos lograr? Una función de la estructura `respuesta ~ predictor` o `y ~ x`, por lo que se configura la sintaxis de `paste` para que obtenga la estructura necesaria de la función:

Para el ejemplo por defecto de la función `selm`

```
library(sn)

data(ais)
m1 <- selm(log(Fe) ~ BMI + LBM, family="SN", data=ais)

print(m1)
Object class: selm 
Call: selm(formula = log(Fe) ~ BMI + LBM, family = "SN", data = ais)
Number of observations: 202 
Number of covariates: 3 (includes constant term)
Number of parameters: 5 
Family: SN 
Estimation method: MLE
Log-likelihood: -175.9094

summary(m1)
Call: selm(formula = log(Fe) ~ BMI + LBM, family = "SN", data = ais)
Number of observations: 202 
Family: SN 
Estimation method: MLE
Log-likelihood: -175.9094 
Parameter type: CP 

CP residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.01862 -0.39918  0.03332  0.40744  1.33000 

Regression coefficients
               estimate  std.err  z-ratio Pr{>|z|}
(Intercept.CP) 2.736823 0.337376 8.112094    0.000
BMI            0.035270 0.020760 1.698934    0.089
LBM            0.009465 0.004467 2.118964    0.034

Parameters of the SEC random component
       estimate std.err
s.d.     0.5796   0.029
```

---

Lo que buscas realizar con los datos del ejemplo anterior:

```
test <- ais[,3:13] # sólo seleccionar numéricas, omitiendo factores

formula <- paste(paste(names(test),collapse = " + "),"~ 1")

formula
"RCC + WCC + Hc + Hg + Fe + BMI + SSF + Bfat + LBM + Ht + Wt ~ 1"

m2 <- selm(formula, family="SN", data=test)

print(m2)
Object class: selm 
Call: selm(formula = formula, family = "SN", data = test)
Number of observations: 202 
Number of covariates: 1 (includes constant term)
Number of parameters: 3 
Family: SN 
Estimation method: MLE
Log-likelihood: -1156.785 

summary(m2)
Call: selm(formula = formula, family = "SN", data = test)
Number of observations: 202 
Family: SN 
Estimation method: MLE
Log-likelihood: -1156.785 
Parameter type: CP 

CP residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-172.60  -54.05   -5.21   46.49  234.87 

Regression coefficients
     estimate std.err z-ratio Pr{>|z|}
mean   571.55    5.34  107.03        0

Parameters of the SEC random component
       estimate std.err
s.d.    75.9946   4.124
gamma1   0.5229   0.160
```

---

**Edición**

Revisé el comentario hecho y concuerdo plenamente con los resultados. Pero, eso no significa que el problema no tenga solución. Para ello me basé nuevamente en un ejemplo del paquete, para que pueda ser reproducible:

```
# Método propuesto en el problema
data(wines)
m28 <- selm(cbind(chloride, glycerol, magnesium) ~ 1, family="ST", data=wines)

extractSECdistr(m28)

Probability distribution of variable 'Fitted SEC distribution of m28'
Skew-elliptically contoured distribution of 3-dimensional family ST
Direct parameters:
                     chloride   glycerol   magnesium
xi                 45.8538776  9.0046044  85.1582507
Omega[chloride,]  830.7641445 -5.7125572 154.9040524
Omega[glycerol,]   -5.7125572  2.0858837   0.7838259
Omega[magnesium,] 154.9040524  0.7838259 292.9647575
alpha               0.5458764 -0.7599728   3.5628470
nu = 4.739759 

# Primera solución
m28b <- selm(chloride + glycerol + magnesium ~ 1, family="ST", data=wines)

extractSECdistr(m28b)

Probability distribution of variable 'Fitted SEC distribution of m28b'
Skew-elliptically contoured distribution of univariate family ST 
Direct parameters:
        xi      omega      alpha         nu 
133.207120  41.408826   2.019968   3.900137 

# Bueno, recurrimos nuevamente a paste con las variables mencionadas anteriormente
variables <- names(wines)[c(15,24,13)]

formula2 <- paste("cbind(", paste(variables,collapse = ", "),") ~ 1")

m28c <- selm(formula2, family="ST", data=wines)

extractSECdistr(m28c)

Probability distribution of variable 'Fitted SEC distribution of m28c'
Skew-elliptically contoured distribution of 3-dimensional family ST
Direct parameters:
                     chloride   glycerol   magnesium
xi                 45.8538776  9.0046044  85.1582507
Omega[chloride,]  830.7641445 -5.7125572 154.9040524
Omega[glycerol,]   -5.7125572  2.0858837   0.7838259
Omega[magnesium,] 154.9040524  0.7838259 292.9647575
alpha               0.5458764 -0.7599728   3.5628470
nu = 4.739759
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Aldo! Estoy haciendo mis primeras experiencias con R y hay cosas que todavía se me escapan.

Fabricio

Comment: Estimado Aldo, lo probé modificando el separador "+" por "," ya que necesito que tome a cada columna de la matriz como variable pero me tira el siguiente error:

formule<-paste(paste(names(mydata),collapse= ","),"~1")
  m3=selm(formule,family="SN",data=mydata,method="MLE")

Comment: Sí, para que tome cada una como variable ocupa el `+`. No es que esté sumando las columnas, sino que está indicando "_ocupa esta, más esta_" y así sucesivamente. Si bien está en inglés, [este documento](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/richard.hahn/teaching/formulanotation.pdf) te ayudará a comprender la sintaxis de las fórmulas dentro de `R`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Lo leo

Comment: Genial, me cuentas que tal te va.

Comment: Aldo, el problema que me encuentro ahora es que en la versión original
obtengo una scatter Matrix: std de 10x10 y gamma de dimensión 10 mientras que cuando reemplazo por ´cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10)~1´  por ´formule´ con el signo ´+´ solo obtengo como salida una sola dimensión. A algo le estoy errando y no me puedo dar cuenta a que.

Comment: Listo, código arreglado y solución lograda

Comment: Perfecto! Ahora si! Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Qué bueno. Si estás satisfecho por la respuesta, te pido aceptarla para cerrar la pregunta. Saludos